# PHP - Mapping objects output to HTML Table

Tags: php, html

i need ideas for mapping object output (data comes from database) to a HTML table.

The table should show name, lastname and the paid months with an tick and not paid months without tick.

This is my object output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(UserlistWithInvoice)#5 (12) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["surname"]=> string(3) "Joe" ["lastname"]=> string(3) "Duo" ["month"]=> string(3) "1,2" ["status"]=> string(3) "1,1" ["year"]=> string(9) "2021,2021" } [1]=> object(UserlistWithInvoice)#6 (12) {["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["surname"]=> string(5) "Djego" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "Mamic" ["month"]=> string(5) "2,3,6" ["status"]=> string(5) "1,1,1" ["year"]=> string(14) "2021,2021,2021" } }
```

with this php code i can show now the names but how could i map the months...

```
<?php foreach ($userlist_with_invoices as $userelement)
    {
        echo '<tr>
            <td><a href="/member.php?userid='. $userelement->id .'">'. $userelement->surname .'</a></td>
            <td>'. $userelement->lastname .'</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>
            <td>&#10004;</td>



        </tr>
';
}
```

Some more information:

- the element "month" shows the months in numeric way.

Value "1,2" in month means -> Invoices for January and February are
available

Value "2,3,6" means invoice are available for february, march and june

- the element "status" shows the paying status for the months (sorted like the element "month")

1: paid 2: not paid 3: rejected

How the result should be:
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You try with my code.
I think you can solved your problem.

```
<?php
   $userlist_with_invoices = UserlistWithInvoice::whereYear('created_at',date('Y'))->get();
   $months = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];

   foreach ($userlist_with_invoices  as $userelement) {
echo '<tr>
<td><a href="/member.php?userid=' . $userelement->id . '">' . $userelement->surname . '</a></td>
<td>' . $userelement->lastname . '</td>';
foreach ($months as $month) {
    if ($userelement->month == $month && $userelement->status == 1) {
        echo '<td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>';
    } elseif ($userelement->month == $month && $userelement->status == 2) {
        echo '<td><i class="fas fa-calendar-times"></i></td>';
    } elseif ($userelement->month == $month && $userelement->status == 3) {
        echo '<td><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>';
    }else {
        echo '<td><i class="fas fa-calendar-times"></i></td>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
} ?>
```